# Initial SessionFactory creation failed./resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: hibernate, maven, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have created Simple project using Maven Hibernate, But project gives me following error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed./resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not     found
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1453)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1475)
at Code.CourseDaoImp.<clinit>(CourseDaoImp.java:16)
at Code.CourseServiceImp.processCourse(CourseServiceImp.java:10)
at Code.app.main(app.java:21)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at Code.CourseDaoImp.<clinit>(CourseDaoImp.java:22)
at Code.CourseServiceImp.processCourse(CourseServiceImp.java:10)
at Code.app.main(app.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
at         org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1453)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1475)
at Code.CourseDaoImp.<clinit>(CourseDaoImp.java:16)
... 2 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Move Java Sources in src/main/java
- *.xml in src/main/resources

> To meet the standards of MAVEN , like that XML will be added 
>   automatically at CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

resources is one of the sources folder of your project. This means that everything it contains is at the roor of the classpath (in the default package). So the code you need is

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```